# Blender crashing when trying to access the viewport shader in blender version 3.5

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, shaders, camera, eevee-render-engine

I am still new to the hardware aspect and using 3D software such as blender .My specs on my desktop is just the bare minimum but it could run blender viewport shading with default settings on version 3.0 to 3.4 but constantly crashes on 3.5 I do not know if it is my specs that are the problem or if my blender is just broken as I have uninstalled and reinstalled blender to version 3.5.

My specs

Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4170 CPU @ 3.70GHz   3.70 GHz

Ram : 8 GB

Display adaptor Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no developers here. We're all volunteer blender users and have no connection with the Blender Foundation so you should report any bugs you find via the Help > Report a Bug menu in Blender.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)